# How to make a Time Picker in jQuery mobile 1.4.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-timepicker

I have the following  time input  in my jQuery mobile app for android , I want to make a time picker for this input as the native Time picker in android devices  . How can i do a time picker in jQuery mobile 1.4.0?

Please help me ...

```
<label for="notifTime"  data-inline="true">
<input  type="time" name="notifTime"  id="notifTime" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the jQuery Mobile Datebox plugin: http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/?

It has a time picker mode that is good as long as you only need hours and minutes.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/KrXe6/)**

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="notifTime">Notification Time:</label>
    <input name="notifTime" id="notifTime" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "useNewStyle":true, "overrideTimeFormat": 12, "themeButton": "b", "themeInput": "a", "theme": "b", "themeHeader": "b"}' />
</div>
```

If you look at the datebox site, there are many options to play with...

Comment: @ezankerThanks a lot ,No I have found mobipick Plugin but its for date only ..  I will try it , many thanks

Comment: plugin link is a 404.